# conversion of ISOformat in python and find minimum value

Tags: python

```
l1 = ["india","pak","usa","bhutan"]

l2= ["ISO10_00_000","ISO5_00_000","ISO1_00_000","ISO3_00_000"]
```

l1 is country and l2 is population of countries after converting it into dictionary India has population is ISO10_00_000,pak has ISO5_00_000 and so on....
so we want minimum population country in the output.
how we can do this.
"ISO10_00_000" what do we mean this and how we convert this in numbers?
thank you in advance.....

Comment: If ISO and underscore was a mistake you can remove it by using string method .replace("ISO",""). This will remove ISO from your populations, you can do similar thing for underscore and get a string with numbers only which can be converted by using int() function.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different ways to achieve this. List comprehension should can do the trick.

```
nums = [int(''.join(i[3:].split("_"))) for i in l2]
country = l1[nums.index(min(nums))]
```

which is essentially the same as doing this:

```
nums = []
for n in l2:
    num = ''.join(n[3:].split('_'))  # removes first 3 letters and removes the _
    num = int(num)  # converts to integer
    nums.append(num)  # adds it to the list nums
min_index = nums.index(min(nums))    # mind the minimum index
country = l1[min_index]             # get the same index in l1
```

output

```
'usa'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> 
>>> l2=["ISO10_00_000","ISO5_00_000","ISO1_00_000","ISO3_00_000"]
>>> 
>>> l2
['ISO10_00_000', 'ISO5_00_000', 'ISO1_00_000', 'ISO3_00_000']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> l2 = [int(v[3:].replace('_','')) for v in l2]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> l2
[1000000, 500000, 100000, 300000]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = ["india","pak","usa","bhutan"]

l2= ["ISO10_00_000","ISO5_00_000","ISO1_00_000","ISO3_00_000"]
```

To get a sorted list:

```
sorted(list(zip(l1,l2)), key=lambda x:int(''.join(n for n in x[-1] if n.isdigit())))
```

To get the smallest country

```
sorted(list(zip(l1,l2)), key=lambda x:int(''.join(n for n in x[-1] if n.isdigit())))[0][0]
```

Comment: This is really smart! Just for my own knowledge, the lambda function is applied on the `l2` only and sort the list based on only integer values it could extract right?

Comment: Pretty much yes, zip will join the l1 and l2 together, and x[-1] in the lambda is saying to use the l2 (last value in combined pair) value for sorting.  I'd suggest looking as just `list(zip(l1,l2))` to get a feel for what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for my just `n.isdigit()` was a bit confusing as I wanted to know whether it iterates over values of `l2` or letters of values in `l2`.